# Why can't I use the as keyword for a struct?

Tags: c#, .net, casting, type-systems, as-operator

I defined the following struct:

```
public struct Call
{
    public SourceFile caller;
    public SourceFile callee;

    public Call(SourceFile caller, SourceFile callee)
    {
        this.caller = caller;
        this.callee = callee;
    }
}
```

Later, I assign it to the Tag property of another object:

```
line.Tag = new Call(sf1, sf2);
```

But when I try to retrieve the Tag property like so,

```
Call call = line.Tag as Call;
```

Visual Studio gives the following compile-time error:

> The operator as must be used within a
>   reference type or nullable type

What is the meaning of that? And how can I solve it?

Comment: Why have you made that a struct? Mutable structs are a bad idea.

Comment: @Mark: +1 And the struct is just going to get boxed for storage in a Tag property anyway...

Comment: Hmm it don't have to be mutable. But I think I should better us a class for this purpose.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

A struct is a value type, so it cannot be used with the `as` operator. The `as` operator must be able to assign a value of null if the cast fails. This is only possible with a reference type or a nullable value type.

There are a couple ways to solve this, but your best bet is to change your `Call` type from a struct to a class. This will essentially change your type from a value type to a reference type, which allows the `as` operator to assign a value of null if the cast fails.

For more information on value types vs. reference types, [this](http://www.albahari.com/valuevsreftypes.aspx) is a decent article. Also, have a look on MSDN:

- [value types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)
- [reference types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/490f96s2.aspx)
- [as-operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)
- [nullable types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cf62fcy%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

Comment: Can't assign null if the cast fails is the key!  +1

Answer (score 37):

Some of the existing answers aren't *quite* right. You can't use *non-nullable* types with `as`, because the result of `as` is the null value of the type if the first operand isn't actually of an appropriate type.

However, you *can* use `as` with value types... if they're nullable:

```
int a = 10;
object o = a;

int? x = o as int?; // x is a Nullable<int> with value 10
long? y = o as long?; // y is a Nullable<long> with the null value
```

So you *could* use:

```
Call? call = line.Tag as Call?;
```

Then you can use it as:

```
if (call != null)
{
    // Do stuff with call.Value
}
```

Two caveats though:

- In my experience this is slower than just using `is` followed by a cast
- You should seriously reconsider your current `Call` type:

  - It's exposing public fields, which is generally poor encapsulation
  - It's a mutable value type, which is almost certainly a mistake

I would strongly suggest you make it a class instead - at which point this problem goes away anyway.

Another thought: if the tag should *always* be a `Call`, then it's better to cast it:

```
Call call = (Call) line.Tag;
```

That way, if the data doesn't match your expectation (i.e. there's some bug such that the `Tag` isn't a `Call`) then you get to find out about it early, rather than after you've potentially done some other work. Note that this cast will behave differently depending on whether `Call` is a struct or a class, if `Tag` is null - you can cast a null value to a variable of a reference type (or a nullable value type), but not to a non-nullable value type.

Answer (score 12):

From the C# Spec

> §7.10.11 The as operator is used to
>   explicitly convert a value to a given
>   **reference type** or **nullable type**. Unlike a cast expression
>   (§7.7.6), the as operator never throws
>   an exception. Instead, if the
>   indicated conversion is not possible,
>   the resulting value is **null**.

References and nullable types can be null. Stucts are value types so they can't be null.

Answer (score 1):

```
Call? call = line.Tag as Call?;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a limitation of C#. If the type were a reference type, then if the cast failed it would simply return 'null', but since it's a value type, it doesn't know what to return when the cast fails.

You must replace your use of as with two: 'is' and 'as'

```
if (line.Tag is Call) {
  call = (Call)line.Tag;
} else {
  // Do whatever you would do if as returned null.
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't call it a "limitation" of C# - that makes it sound like something that should be fixed. It's a *restriction* which is natural based on what the "as" operator is meant to do.

Comment: Maybe. There were other valid design points. C# 1.0 could have made the expression 'x as T' return default(T) if x was not explicitly convertible to T. With the introduction of nullable types, C# could have made the return type of 'x as T' Nullable<T> when T is a value type.

Comment: (I should also say that given the number of times new programmers trip over the as-on-value-types thing, "limitation" is an accurate description in my opinion.)

Answer (score -1):

What is the meaning - As stated, structures are value types.

How can I solve it - Change it to

```
Call call = line.Tag;
```