# Get structure back from Cache fails with cast error when types looks the same

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following structure:

```
struct someData
{
    public bool check;
    public string text;
}

...

someData sd = new someData(){ check = true, text = "just testing" };
Cache.Insert(cacheInd, sd, null, Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(90));
```

Then later on the code, I want to retrieve the data from cache, but I get an InvalidCastException:

```
if (Cache[cacheInd] != null)
{
   someData sd = (someData)Cache[cacheInd];//Error here
```

If I try this:

```
someData sd = Cache[cacheInd] as someData;
```

I get:

> The as operator must be used with a reference type or nullable type ('ASP._dev_pull_aspx.someData' is a non-nullable value type)

Any ideas on how to solve it?

Here's what I'm doing:

1. Load page (not cached yet) -> everything is fine
2. Reload it (cached) -> everything is fine
3. Change code, not related to it somewhere else in the page -> get the exception
4. Recycling the cache *fixes* it (until i change code again)

Note: thanks for MethodMan and   Michael Humelsine for explanation of `as` failure - [Why can't I use the as keyword for a struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4401344/why-cant-i-use-the-as-keyword-for-a-struct), but failure to perform cast is still unclear especially since it works most of the time.

Comment: `A struct is a value type, so it cannot be used with the as operator. The as operator must be able to assign a value of null if the cast fails`

Comment: Checkout some fully detailed explanations from previous posting especially from `Jon Skeet` which of whom is highly respected in the .net community http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4401344/why-cant-i-use-the-as-keyword-for-a-struct

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov It's "someData"

Comment: MethodMan is correct.  Use a reference type (class).  Your struct is mutable which is never a good idea. By making your struct a class this problem goes away.

Comment: You cannot use nonnullable types with the 'as' operator because it cannot assign null if the cast fails.  This would not be an issue with a reference type.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov " System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid."

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Please check my edit, not sure if it helps

Comment: Based on your further description... when you change the code elsewhere in the page it will recompile... the cache will be lost when the app pool resets due to the code changes... does the path by which you then load the page and hit the cache ensure that the cache has been repopulated?  Make sure the cache is consistently loaded.

Comment: @Cornwell I believe the behavior is expected - see my answer.

Comment: @MichaelHumelsine - based on OP edit using reference type would definitely not solve the issue but simply fail with a bit more detailed, but equally confusing error about the same type could not be casted to itself.

Comment: @JaredPeless thanks for very important part of the puzzle - "the page it will recompile." - this is the reason of "typeof(someData) !=  typeof(someData)" error - see my answer (no recycle -> there are 2 identically looking types).

Comment: If someData was a reference type then var sd = Cache[id] as someData would evaluate to *null* then an if(sd != null) check would provide the results the OP is after.  I understand your answer and think it is correct.  I still think a simple change to a reference type would fix the issue also.

Comment: @Cornwell check out my edits - feel free to rollback. I'm also planning to remove all my comments as I've rolled them in into the answer... Self-destructs in 30...29...

Comment: @MichaelHumelsine yes `as` would give `null` (somewhat safer but still as puzzling). Original code with cast `someData sd = (someData)Cache[cacheInd];` would still fail with an exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you get 2 *different* types with type named the same as result of re-compilation of the page and hence you can't cast one to another despite very similar names/structure.

Why:

- in .Net type identity includes full name and assembly identity (name) like "System.Int32 from System.dll v4.0.0.0".
- changing an ASPX/CSHTML page produces new assembly with random name but *does not* trigger recycle of app-domain (especially in debug configuration) till some relatively high threshold of "number of dynamically  compiled assemblies" is hit (don't have good link handy, search. I.e. [this one](http://forums.asp.net/t/1931153.aspx?View+Compilation) talks about diff between ASPX vs. Razor )

You should be able to see complete types if you compare whole `Type` objects (`typeof(someData)` vs. `Cache[cacheInd].GetType()` - one of the properties would be different, i.e. [`Type.FullName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.fullname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) likely candidate.

I'd expect the types to look similar to following (with difference in the name of its assembly):

- {`ASP._dev_pull_aspx.someData` from "ASP._dev_pull_aspx.**_3333**.dll"
- {`ASP._dev_pull_aspx.someData` from "ASP._dev_pull_aspx.**_7777**.dll"

To fix you should move types you care about to compiled assemblies from pages or live with the fact that sometimes types will not match and restart app-domain. Normally rebuilding project or web.config change would trigger app-domain recycle as it is part of recycle triggers along with number of recompilations of individual pages.

Notes:

- changing `struct someData` to `class someData` would still reproduce the error, but you may see more detailed message instead with as types still will be different
- the other common cases of such error are having *copy* of the same type in several assemblies/namespaces due to code sharing (as in include the same source file into multiple project) and using multiple versions of the same strongly named assembly.

Comment: That's very interesting and it makes sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Well, I just tested a struct like yours, stored it in cache and retrieved it with the cast syntax (i.e. (someData)Cache[cacheInd]).

It worked fine with no casting issues and no exceptions.  What is the value of the "cacheInd" variable in your example?  Can it change between the time it is used to store the item in the cache and the time it retrieves it?

Have you debugged to see what the data type is of the object/struct that IS stored in the cache?

The lack of issues I faced seem to point to something other than an issue with serializing/deserializing a struct.

Comment: Thanks. Please check my edit, not sure if it helps understanding the problem better. cacheInd does not get changed, I've replaced it with text and I get the same.