# Cannot add constraint for an interface

Tags: c#, interface, constraints

I have this interface:

```
namespace Common.Extensions
{
    public interface IExtension
    {
        string FriendlyName { get; }
        string Description { get; }
    }
}
```

In other class method, I have this definition:

```
public void LoadExtensions<T>(T tipo) where T : Common.Extensions.IExtension
{

}
```

Inside the body of that method, I have this:

```
T extension = Activator.CreateInstance(t) as T;
```

Where "t" is a type loaded dynamically from a DLL. That type implements IExtension interface.

With that code, I receive this compile time error:

```
The type parameter 'T' cannot be used with the 'as' operator because it does not have a class type constraint nor a 'class' constraint
```

According to documentation, what I am trying to do is valid. What is missing here?

Jaime

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `as` operator can only be used with reference types or nullable types ([reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/as)). If the interface is implemented by a struct `as` will not work with it.

You can either constrain `T` to be a class

```
public void LoadExtensions(T tipo) where T : class, Common.Extensions.IExtension
```

Or you can use a regular cast:

```
T extension = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(t);
```

**NOTE**

You could also add a `new()` constraint to the method to force `T` to have a default constructor to avoid runtime issues, and not use a cast at all:

```
public static void LoadExtensions<T>(T tipo) where T : IExtension, new()
{
    T extension = new T();
}
```

Comment: Thanks.. that worked.. however. I wondering why this does work: "IModule module = Activator.CreateInstance(t) as IModule". I have this in other part of the code. So, the "as" operator is not working when using with a constraint, but when using an interface name, it works.

Comment: IModule is an interface

Comment: @SteveHarris but according to this answer. the "as" operator can be used only for classes what is not true since I can use it for IModule interface.

Comment: @jstuardo It works because generic methods are compiled for each instantiation and are optimized for the type of `T` (struct or class) they are compiled for to avoid boxing.

Comment: @jstuardo Added reference to the fact that `as` is not compatible with structs (I meant reference types, not necessarily classes, my bad). References to interfaces always behave as reference types even if the implementer is a struct, and in this case the struct will be boxed

Comment: Activator.CreateInstance creates an instance of a class. A class can be referenced as an interface. The issue you were having was that using the generic T cast, the compiler needed to know that T is constrained to a class.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using the `as` operator, it is obvious that `T` [cannot be a `struct`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4401360/7571171), it will only ever be a `class`.

Therefore, you could just do what the error message says and **add the class constraint** like this:

```
public void LoadExtensions<T>(T tipo) where T : class, Common.Extensions.IExtension
{                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the class keyword to constrain as a class:

```
public void LoadExtensions<T>(T tipo) where T : class, Common.Extensions.IExtension
```

But IMO you should use the interface as you do not need to know the type to access it's methods:

```
Common.Extensions.IExtension extension = (Common.Extensions.IExtension)Activator.CreateInstance(t);
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could explain your answer as well.

Comment: please add some explanation of solution

Comment: I cannot do such a cast since this a plugin type interface, what is dynamic. The application that uses the plugin should  manage a derived interface, not IExtension interface..... I need to use IExtension interface only in this piece of code to access a specific property common to all classes. So, the "as" to T is prefered in this case.