# How can I find out the type of data from the generic type

Tags: c#

I have a method in which I send two arguments of the same type and I need to fold them. For example, if these are numbers, then return only the sum, and if the lines are the concatenation of these lines. How can I do it? And if I pass a type that cannot be folded, then I need to throw an exception.

```
public class Calcul<T>
{
    public static T Add(T c1, T c2)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you might want to use overloads, not generics. How many types can T be?

Comment: Any types, the fact of the matter is that you can use any, but if only you can work with them.

Comment: "For example, if these are numbers, then return only the sum, **and if the lines are the concatenation of these lines**." I've read the bold part several times and I still don't get what you're trying to say.

Comment: This is something like a calculator for all types of data.

Comment: So what do you want to do if someone passes in two `HashSet<string>` instances, or a `Transaction`, or a `Window`?  How do you intend to "add" those things?

Comment: just adding the c1 and c2 will concatenate if they are string and sum them up if they are summable types. What would you do if c1 and c2 are objects?

Comment: if they are objects, I will just throw an exception. I need to process only those types that I can handle.

Comment: Don't make the method generic if it's not actually generic, and don't say the method can accept any type if it can't in fact accept any type.  As you've already been told, if you want to handle a finite number of specific types, have overloads for each of those types.

Comment: Alas, I showed the teacher, but he said that it was not that. He said that it should be something like an abstract calculator where for each type T you can define the operation N

Answer (score 1):

[Servy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1159478/servy) said [in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55972933/how-can-i-find-out-the-type-of-data-from-the-generic-type?noredirect=1#comment98597142_55972933):

> Don't make the method generic if it's not actually generic, and don't say the method can accept any type if it can't in fact accept any type. As you've already been told, if you want to handle a finite number of specific types, have overloads for each of those types.

to which you [replied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55972933/how-can-i-find-out-the-type-of-data-from-the-generic-type?noredirect=1#comment98597244_55972933):

> Alas, I showed the teacher, but he said that it was not that. He said that it should be something like an abstract calculator where for each type T you can define the operation N

---

You can have your method with that signature and no `if` blocks at all, but the `Add` method can't be static. You have to pass in a [`Func<T1, T2, TResult>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.func-3) where `T1`, `T2`, and `TResult` are the same (`T`):

```
public class Calculator<T>
{
    private readonly Func<T, T, T> _func;

    public Calculator(Func<T, T, T> func)
    {
        _func = func;
    }

    public T Add(T a, T b)
    {
        return _func(a, b);
    }
}
```

You'd use it like this:

```
Func<int, int, int> intAddition = (a, b) => a + b;
var intCalculator = new Calculator<int>(intAddition);
Console.WriteLine(intCalculator.Add(1, 2)); // writes 3

Func<string, string, string> stringAddition = (a, b) => a + b;
var stringCalculator = new Calculator<string>(stringAddition);
Console.WriteLine(stringCalculator.Add("Hello ", "world")); // writes "Hello world"
```

Online example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/8NOBsv

---

This way you get to specify the logic of the `Add` method, and you don't have loads of overloaded methods (or awful type-checking logic inside the method like `if ( typeof(T) == typeof(string) )`, etc.

Comment: @ДинарВалитов I think this should answer your question. Can you add the details in the comments to the question and restructure it?

Answer (score 0):

You can `typeof(T)` to get the type information always. Using that, you can use conditional statements to work your way through the logic

Example:

```
var type = typeof(T);
if (type == int)
{ do something ;}
```

Generics are used for cases like : 2 different types following the same operations but taking different input types and output types. The underlying usage is that they have the same processes. If you are using type specific processes much, then its better to overload your functions to suit your need.

Reading more into your use case:

Try overloading methods.

```
private static int doSomething(int n1, int n2)
    {           
        return (n1) + (n2);  
    }

    private static float doSomething(float n1, float n2)
    {
        return (n1) - (n2);
    }
```

Comment: This is yes, but how can I get this particular object, I will not be able to assign an object of type T to an object that I receive from typeof(T). I am just new to C #, so please write more clearly.

Comment: @ДинарВалитов to assign the result you can cast the item like this ((c1 as int) + (c2 as int)).

Comment: You can do it like you, but there are a lot of data types, I don’t want to do much if

Comment: @ДинарВалитов You must do much if. C# provides no way to do what you want.

Comment: But then I have to write for each type of operation and there will be a lot of methods, and I want to make it use less code.

Comment: [Why can't I use the as keyword for a struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4401344/1364007)

Comment: @ДинарВалитов I want a blonde in a red Ferrari.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a generic way that works as long as T supports the + operator. However, it uses runtime checking. As far as I can tell there is no way to use type constraints to check this at compile time.

Adapted from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5997156/6713871

```
public class Calcul<T>
{
    public static T Add(T c1, T c2)
    {
        return (dynamic)c1 + (dynamic)c2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have said you should probably use overloads. However it's possible to do something like this

```
static class Calc<T>
{
    public static T Add(T a, T b)
    {
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(int))
        {
            return (T)(object)((int)(object)a + (int)(object)b);
        }

        if (typeof(T) == typeof(uint))
        {
            return (T)(object)((uint)(object)a + (uint)(object)b);
        }

        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException($"Type {typeof(T).Name} is not supported.");
    }    
}
```

And call it with:

```
Calc<int>.Add(1 , 2); // returns 3
Calc<double>.Add(2d, 3d).Dump(); // throws exception
```

Comment: What is `Dump()`?